# using map to check for true or false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, filter

I am trying no to use a loop as Im practicing map, filter etc. and wonder why my code doesn't work?

```
function checking(array,item){
 var temporary=true;
array.map(function(x){
if (x!=item){
    temporary=false;
}

});
return temporary;
}

checking([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

Comment: Please format/indent your code. Why are you using `map` without returning anything from the callback and without doing anything with the result? That's the semantics of `forEach`. Why would you set `temporary` to `false` for each and every element if it's not equal to the input? And why didn't you simply figure out the problem by stepping through your code in the debugger? if you're studying `map` and `filter` how did you miss `some`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), it is perfect for checking and returnig a boolean value. And the best is the short circuit if the callback return is `true`.

```js
function checking(array, item) {  
    return array.some(function (x) {
        return x === item;
    });
}

document.write(checking([1, 2, 3], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not checking if 2 is in array, but you are checking if array has a different value than 2.

You should wether check if it there eg :

```
let temporary=false;
array.map(function(x){
if (x==item){
    temporary=true;
}
```

Comment: no i do check if 2 is in an array- thats what the map function is for-exactly to check elements OF an array, not array itself.